# Вывод переменных в графическом режиме в паскале

Tags: переменные, pascal, freepascal

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в графическом режиме в паскале не выводится переменная, когда пишу `outtextxy(x,y,p[i]);`, при этом `p` это интеджеровский массив.

**Обновление**

Что я не так делаю, подскажите, пожалуйста. При этом коде выводится только последний элемент, т.e. когда `i=k`:

```
uses crt,graph;
var k,i,m,dr,md:integer;
    pr,par:string;
p:array[1..100] of real;
BEGIN
  readln(k);
  for i:=1 to k do readln(p[i]);
  initgraph(dr,md,' ');
  for i:=1 to k do
    str(p[i],pr);
  for i:=1 to k do begin
    str(i,par);
    setcolor(i);
    outtextxy(100+80*(i-1),430,pr[i]);
    outtextxy(100+80*(i-1),440,par[i]);
    readln;
    end;
END.
```

Comment: @VeFox, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, выводите цветом фона и просто не можете увидеть вывод.
Возможно, элемент с индексом i отсутствует в массиве.
Возможно, вы не видите вывод, т.к. x или y выходят за границы экрана.
Возможно, не активирован графический режим или еще что-нибудь.

**Обновление**

По-моему, у тебя все выводится на одних и тех же местах на экране. Ты же координату у не меняешь. Поэтому ты и видишь только последнее выведенное значение. Кстати, зачем там readln? Я уже не помню паскаль, но, по-моему, readln используется для считывания введенных значений. Для смены строк в графическом режиме пользуйся изменением координаты y.

**Обновление**

Да, ты прав. А что происходит, когда ты выводишь pr[i]? В строке str(i,par) ты перевел  счетчик i из integer в string и присвоил значение переменной par. Что ты хочешь получить из строки, состоящей из одного символа по индексу больше 1? Разве str() при передаче в нее вторым параметром непустой строки дописывает ее вместо банального присваивания нового значения?

Comment: Что я не так делаю, подскажите, пожалуйста.  
При этом коде выводится только последний элемент, т.e. когда i=k:

    uses crt,graph;
    var k,i,m,dr,md:integer;
        pr,par:string;
    p:array[1..100] of real;
    BEGIN
      readln(k);
      for i:=1 to k do readln(p[i]);
      initgraph(dr,md,' ');
      for i:=1 to k do
        str(p[i],pr);
      for i:=1 to k do begin
        str(i,par);
        setcolor(i);
        outtextxy(100+80*(i-1),430,pr[i]);
        outtextxy(100+80*(i-1),440,par[i]);
        readln;
        end;
    END.

Comment: Отформатируйте код, выделив его и нажав иконку {} над полем ввода текста.

Comment: Какой смысл менять у, если в итоге у меня просто должна получиться строка (находящаяся как раз на этом самом у). Накладываться не может по одной простой причине, там разные x.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
for i:=1 to k do
str(p[i],pr[i]); // здесь забыли дописать [i] к pr, если я правильно понял.
```

Использовать строки для хранения массивов - дурной тон. Правильно объявить `pr` и `par` как `array [1..100] of string`.

А еще лучше написать вот так:

```
var
  ElementsCount: Integer;
  i, m, dr, md: Integer;
  pr, par: string;
  p: array [1..100] of real;
BEGIN
  ReadLn(ElementsCount); // что будет, если напишут букву вместо цифры? Или 101?
  for i := 1 to ElementsCount do
    ReadLn(p[i]);  // что будет, если напишут букву вместо цифры?
  InitGraph(dr, md, ' '); // Не нужно в dr и md что-то записать перед вызовом?
  for i := 1 to ElementsCount do
  begin
    SetColor(i);
    str(p[i], pr);
    OutTextXY(100+80*(i-1), 430, pr);
    str(i, par);
    OutTextXY(100+80*(i-1), 440, par);
    ReadLn;  // нужно будет жать `ввод` после вывода каждого элемента
  end;
END.
```